# How can I change Skype user status from online to away using skype4com?

Tags: c#, .net, skype, skype4com

How can I change my Skype status (from online to away, offline) using skype4com dll? I am working in C#. Answers that provide sample code would be most helpful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have attached to skype you just need to call ChangeUserStatus method:

```
var skype = new Skype();
skype.Attach(5, true);
skype.ChangeUserStatus(TUserStatus.cusAway);
```

Comment: have any idea how to change the status?i mean if i want to add near my online icon a message or a link to a music..how can do that?

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess that: skype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText = 'I'm listening 3 Doors Down'; should do.

You can find more info here: http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Comment: Is it required to call skype.Attach(5, true); ? For me the sample works even without it.

Comment: Based on the Attach method docs ("This command establishes a connection to Skype") I'd assume it is required.

Comment: Seems that this link (developer.skype.com) does not work any more. Do you have any other link (maybe @Microsoft)?

Comment: What I found so far is: [Skype for Business API SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/appsdk/apioverview)

Comment: I found an unofficial api manual that someone posted online: https://documentation.help/Skype4COM/group__sk4com.html#ga1d58cda22ab127c99195ee3871ee7953

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the `GET USERSTATUS` command via the [Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) ("Skype Accessories"), which enables you to get or set the user's status.

The API reference documentation is [here](http://developer.skype.com/resources/public_api_ref.zip).

Comment: the answer is not for skype4com, is it?

Comment: It is in that skype4com is a set of objects representing the Skype API.

Comment: Seems that this link (developer.skype.com) does not work any more. Do you have any other link (maybe @Microsoft)?

Comment: @Matt Here is a link to the accessories page. https://web.archive.org/web/20111120064630/http://developer.skype.com/accessories  The waybackmachine is a cool tool for resurrecting dead websites/pages.  See also: https://web.archive.org/web/20111121201801/http://developer.skype.com/public-api-reference